# How to add links to list item in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I tried adding links through calculated columns but later found that it has been removed from SharePoint 2013. Is there a way where I can add links to the list items?

Comment: `I tried` then post what have you done so far

Comment: There are several workarounds here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/233833#233833

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add links to list item, we can use Hyperlink field to achieve it.

[image]

If you want to add multiple links to a list item, we can use Multiple line of text field to achieve it.